# Same number of a character in two parts of a regex

Tags: regex, preg-replace

I'll start by saying I am using PHP and preg_replace

I have created some regex `/(={2,6})\W+(={2,6})/` to try and match

```
Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem 
==Etymology==

==Links==

Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem
```

(http://pastebin.com/5kAKQM1x)

so that I can turn it into

```
Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem 
==Etymology==
<<My Insert Here>>
==Links==

Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem
```

(http://pastebin.com/aamRSXU4)

The problem is my regex also matches

```
Ussher believed the whole creation process occurred on that day.

==Religious views==

===Jewish traditions===
In rabbinic writings and the
```

(http://pastebin.com/HJ2Vy7Md)

How can I ensure that there are the same number of `=`'s signs on boths sides? How do I use `{2,6}` differently.

Answer (score 3):

Use back reference 
`/(={2,6})\W+\1/`

Answer (score 1):

use a backreference to the previous capture

```
(={2,6})(\S+)(\1)
```

(I assume you mean \S+ and not \W+)...